# How to get the Android API version at runtime from Delphi Rio?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

In my Java code, I can easily test the current API level at runtime with something like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
   doSomething();
}
```

How can I find the equivalent of `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` in Delphi Rio?

I tried to look for [`int android_get_application_target_sdk_version()`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/apilevels#group__apilevels_1gac8c055c08fb8f886f238c5d15750be41) but I cannot find a Delphi unit containing that.

On the other hand, I found a [`function AConfiguration_getSdkVersion(Config: PAConfiguration)`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/configuration#aconfiguration_getsdkversion) in the Androidapi.Configuration unit, but it needs a `PAConfiguration` as parameter, and I don't know how to get one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.Os;

...

  if TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK_INT > SomeValue then
```

Where the value of SomeValue is the API level you want to check against.

Comment: Thank you. I tried
if TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK_INT >= TJBuild_VERSION_CODES.JavaClass.O then doSomething;
but I had to replace TJBuild_VERSION_CODES.JavaClass.O with a hardcoded integer to avoid an exception.
Could you complete your answer with TJBuild_VERSION_CODES.JavaClass.xxx please?

Comment: Why would I add something that potentially causes an exception? As you've discovered, it's better to use an hardcoded integer.

Comment: I understand your point of view. You're right. I just don't like "magic numbers". Constants are better.

Comment: The problem is that, as you've discovered, `TJBuild_VERSION_CODES.JavaClass.O` isn't defined in earlier SDK's which is somewhat akin to a catch-22.